# if index.html does not exist in subdirectory go to

Tags: apache, .htaccess, rules

I have a site in the Apache, that the folder is:

```
/var/www/html/content
```

at this level I have an `index.html`

```
/var/www/html/content/index.html
```

and I have a lot of subfolders, but not all of them has a `index.html`

so I want if someone go to: `http://example.com/subfolder/subfolder`, and this subfolder does not contain an `index.html`, redirect to: `http://example.com/`

I tried with an `.htaccess` file in the content folder, with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L]
```

but Apache shows me this:

> Internal Server Error

Comment: what does the error log say?

Comment: "subfolder does not contain an index.html, redirect to: `http://example.com/`" - Do you explicitly want to "redirect" to the root, or to simply serve `index.html` from the root (as your rule is trying to do)?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L]
> ```

This would result in an Internal Server Error (500 response) if mod_rewrite is not enabled on your server, or `/index.html` does not exist (which would seem unlikely given by what you've stated in the question).

However, you don't seem to need mod_rewrite at all here.

If you want to serve `index.html` from the directory being requested (if it exists), otherwise default to serving `/index.html` from the document root (no external redirect) then you can simply modify the `DirectoryIndex`. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html /index.html
```

The `DirectoryIndex` directive lists the files to try when requesting a directory. In this case, `index.html` refers to a file in the currently requested directory. If this does not exist then it tries `/index.html` (a root-relative URL) in the document root.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Answer (score 0):

Your rewire conditions are saying only rewrite to index.html if the request is for a file or folder that does not exist i.e. anyone that requests a file or folder that exists will prevent the rewrite rule from activating, thus very easily bypassing what you are trying to do.

Anyway your going about the thing the wrong way in the first place, what you should be doing is restricting access to all directories and then only allowing access into the directories that you want users to get into. Placing index files in directories is just a fail safe for incompediant developers who can't configure apache restrictions correctly.

Comment: ok, let me check that, I'm a beginner in apache, so I don't have idea of how to do that, let me try to search something about this, thanks for your comments

Comment: "Placing index files in directories is just a fail safe for incompediant developers who can't configure apache restrictions correctly" - Who says the OP is trying to restrict access? It looks like they are just using the `DirectoryIndex` to serve content and have URLs of the form `/contact/`. The default action is to serve a 403 Forbidden for any directory that does not have an index document (assuming mod_autoindex is not enabled) - but maybe this is not desirable?